# error: expected expression before ‘if’

Tags: c, macros, syntax-error

Here is my code, I don't know where I'm wrong and what is "expression"?

```
#define m(smth) (if(sizeof(smth) == sizeof(int)) {printf("%d", (int) smth);} else{puts((char*)smth);})

int main(void) {
    m("smth");
}
```

here is output:

```
/home/roroco/Dropbox/rbs/ro_sites/c/ex/ex2.c: In function ‘main’:
/home/roroco/Dropbox/rbs/ro_sites/c/ex/ex2.c:18:18: error: expected expression before ‘if’
 #define m(smth) (if(sizeof(smth) == sizeof(int)) {printf("%d", (int) smth);} else{puts((char*)smth);})
                  ^
/home/roroco/Dropbox/rbs/ro_sites/c/ex/ex2.c:21:5: note: in expansion of macro ‘m’
     m("smth");
     ^
make[3]: *** [ex/CMakeFiles/ex2.dir/ex2.c.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [ex/CMakeFiles/ex2.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [ex/CMakeFiles/ex2.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [ex2] Error 2
```

Comment: You do realise that on some systems/compilers, the size of a `int` is different from the size of a `pointer`. Which means that the following `printf("%d", (int) smth);` happens to be `cast from pointer to integer of different size`

Answer (score 7):

`(if(expression) {} else {})` is not valid syntax.

Try

```
#define m(smth) if(sizeof(smth) == sizeof(int)) {printf("%d", (int) smth);} else{puts((char*)smth);}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't enclose a block in C in braces (`()`) - just remove them, and you should be OK. Also, it probably won't be a bad idea to surround calls to `smth` with braces:

```
#define m(smth) if(sizeof(smth) == sizeof(int)) {printf("%d", (int) (smth));} else{puts((char*)(smth));}
```